# JSP Set variable based on dynamic date

Tags: jsp

I'm adding a class to an element if the date is over 30 days old.

I've added the date as a hardcoded string and the variable works, but not when I tried to do it dynamically.

```
<s:property value="#record.surveyDate.before('05/01/2019') ? 'old' : 'new'"/>
```

This works, how can I have dynamic code that will mean "30 days before today" instead of the hardcoded date?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to include the version that didn't work? In any case, is this Struts 2? In which case you don't want a property, you want to output something based *on* a property?

Comment: @DaveNewton, I don't know how to write this dynamically, since I've only used properties like this in this version, I believe Struts 2. I can do this with multiple lines of backend code, but not in the front end.

Comment: Well, it *should* be on the back end; views should be as simple as possible. You "believe" Struts 2? You should probably find out. Then check out some S2 tutorials.

Comment: Going to do that route, thanks.